# Memory Uses In ios Simulator And Device

Tags: ios, ipad, memory, ios-simulator

When i run app in Simulator my app is use Memory 14 MB.
But When i run app in Device(iPad iOS 7) That time my app is using 422MB.
And ARC = YES.

give me any idea what is problem....![image]

Comment: You should run with the allocations tool in Instruments (Product -> Profile) in Xcode, and select the allocations tool when Instruments prompts you.  This tool will help you to identify which parts of your program are allocating a large amount of memory.  When you narrow down the relevant code you may see why there's a difference between the simulator and the device, or at least you can post the relevant code in your question so we'll have an easier time helping you.

Comment: Have you "Enabled Zombie Objects" ?

Answer (score 0):

are u using any type of resource e.g like video or audio file and u have add them in bundle of your app

So, don't add them in bundle that increase your app size in device

Answer (score -1):

use Instrument to check the any possible memory leak.
Product->Profile->Memory Leak.